# losing some points while drawing points in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have made a c++ code in openGL to draw seven vertices. My sample code is as follows:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init2D(float r, float g, float b)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
    glPointSize(4.0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //draw two points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(30, 30);
    glVertex2i(47, 76);
    glVertex2i(76, 150);
    glVertex2i(130, 240);
    glVertex2i(300, 200);
    glVertex2i(250, 50);
    glVertex2i(60, 20);
    glEnd();

   glFlush();
 }

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("points and lines");
    init2D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

But when I run the code, I am only getting 4 of them. Is there anything wrong in the code? Is there any way of displaying all the points?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
> ```

You are setting up your projection such that (0,0) maps to the bottom left corner, and (200, 150) to the top right corner, hence

> ```
> glVertex2i(130, 240);
> glVertex2i(300, 200);
> glVertex2i(250, 50);
> ```

are all outside of the view volume.

Comment: @user6843794: Adjust the `gluOrtho2D()` call so view frustum encompasses all the points.